# Setting a column's values to calculated values throughout the rest of the syntax

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am familiar with basic sql for querying data.  I've learned it through generating queries from our company's software that essentially uses a drag-and-drop GUI interface that generates the syntax.  I've been trying to read about how to do what I am asking about below, but it is all too difficult for me to understand.  For security purposes in the distribution of queried tables, I need to be able to mask id numbers of students in any query results going forward by using a private calculation on all id numbers.  When I use this calculation in the select statement itself, it works fine in very basic queries, but when I try to use it in a query that is more complex, like in a query with a subquery, it doesn't work.  From my research, it seems like I need to be using a SET or DECLARE statement so that the syntax knows that going forward, the column values of id_num are really something like (id_num)/2*12, but what I've been trying from the examples aren't working.  I am using SQL Server 2008.

In short, can someone please explain if there is a way to convert all the values in a column throughout a query's syntax (including in subqueries) to a calculation on that column's values instead of their actual values?

Pseudo code something like this:

SET masked_id = SUM(mytable.id_num/2*12) AS mytable.masked_id

SELECT masked_id
FROM mytable

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The question that I asked was unrelated to the issue that I was experiencing.  I assumed that I needed to declare or set the variable with the calculation, but I was alternatively missing some syntax that I have since corrected.  Detailing that correction would not help (and could confuse) anyone in the future reading this who might have a similar question.

Thank you,

Lindsay